# In vue3, the value of progress in fake-progress is not updated in the view, it is always 0

Tags: vuejs3, progress-bar, progress

in vue3,I want to add a progress bar for network requests,so i use [fake-progress](https://github.com/piercus/fake-progress),but i can use it, because its value is not responsive
there is my code :

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ progress }}
        <!-- <el-progress type="circle" :percentage="parseInt(progress * 100)"></el-progress> -->
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import FakeProgress from 'fake-progress';
import { reactive, toRef, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue';

let fake = new FakeProgress({
    timeConstant: 1000,
    autoStart: true,
})

let fakeRef = reactive(fake)
let progress = toRef(fakeRef, 'progress')

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(fake.progress);
    console.log(fakeRef.progress);
    console.log(progress);
}, 1);

</script>
```

all of the value is changed, but in the view {{progress}} is always 0
how can i do it? why is this，wuwuwu

I want the numbers on the page to be changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FakeProgress isn't a vue reactive. So we need to add some reactivity here...

A simple solution would be to override the `progress` property and update your progress ref on changes:

[The live gist is here.](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import FakeProgress from 'fake-progress';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const fake = new FakeProgress({
    timeConstant: 1000,
    autoStart: true,
});

const progress = ref(0);

Object.defineProperty(fake, 'progress', {
  set(val){
    progress.value = val;
  },
  get(){
    return progress.value;
  }
});

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ progress }}
    </div>
</template>
```

A more clever solution would be to provide a reactive object as `this` to construct a FakeProgress's instance:

[The live gist is here.](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import {FakeProgress} from './fake-progress.js';
import { reactive } from 'vue';

// create our custom reactive instance
const fake = reactive({});

// set prototype
Object.setPrototypeOf(fake, FakeProgress.prototype);

// call constructor
FakeProgress.bind(fake)({
    timeConstant: 1000,
    autoStart: true,
});

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        {{ fake.progress }}
    </div>
</template>
```